# Script doesn't work anymore after jQuery update

Tags: jquery

I just updated my jQuery from `jquery-1.6.1.min.js` to `jquery-1.8.2.js` and now this piece of code doesn't work anymore:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.freezebg').click(function() {
        var ftop = $('.sort-wrap').offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
        var fleft = $('.sort-wrap').offset().left;
        $('.sort-wrap').css({position: 'fixed', left: fleft + 'px', top: ftop + 'px'});
});
$(".unfreezebg").click(function() {
    $('.sort-wrap').css({position: 'absolute',left:'auto',top: 'auto'});
        return false;
    });
});
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cboxOverlay").addClass("unfreezebg");
});
</script>
```

Does anyone have a clue why?

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: try ``.bind('load', handler)`` as ``load`` is deprecated in 1.8

Comment: I don't get any errors... ( maybe wordpress doesn't show them)

Comment: You should see errors in your console tool for your browser.

Comment: @doniyor: Could you be more precise where to add .bind('load', handler). I'm an absolute beginner. Thanks!

Comment: there's nothing wrong with the code you have posted that would cause it to stop working without error. The problem is probably elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, you're probably right, Kevin B. I will have to test the whole thing again and will post here later on. Anyways, thanks for your help guys, really appreciated!

Comment: Yes, it did work after I deleted `jQuery.noConflict()` which was included somewhere near the footer of my Worpress. So in the end it didn't have anything to do with the wrong version of my jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

try `.on('load', handler)` since `.load()` is deprecated in 1.8.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   $(window).on('load',function(){
    $('.freezebg').click(function() {    
      var ftop = $('.sort-wrap').offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
      var fleft = $('.sort-wrap').offset().left;
      $('.sort-wrap').css({position: 'fixed', left: fleft + 'px', top: ftop + 'px'});
    });
    $(".unfreezebg").click(function() {
      $('.sort-wrap').css({position: 'absolute',left:'auto',top: 'auto'});   
      return false;   
    });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: No, it doesn't. Really strange. Edit: Some additional info: jquery-1.6.1.min had sizzle.js included and version 1.8.2 does not. Maybe because of this?

Comment: what error are you getting, can you see in FF console? - something like 'function blabla is undefined' ?

Comment: I just tested your update and still nothing happens. I checked firebug console for errors, but there hasn't been listed anything. Hmm..

Comment: all versions of jQuery since 1.3.2 had sizzle included

Answer (score 0):

[`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is the "new way":

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   $(window).on('load',function(){
    $('.freezebg').on('click', function() {    
      var ftop = $('.sort-wrap').offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
      var fleft = $('.sort-wrap').offset().left;
      $('.sort-wrap').css({position: 'fixed', left: fleft + 'px', top: ftop + 'px'});
    });
    $(".unfreezebg").on('click', function() {
      $('.sort-wrap').css({position: 'absolute',left:'auto',top: 'auto'});   
      return false;   
    });
   });
</script>
```

`.on` is the standard right now, and you should start using it, as it works as both `.click(...` and `.live('click'...`